# How to install EasyGUI on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard)?

Tags: python, macos, easygui

I would like to install [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) on Mac OS X 10.6, but am running into trouble. Has anyone successfully done this? If so, what explicit set of steps did you follow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know what ***running into trouble*** means but, nonetheless, something like this *seems* to work on 10.6:

```
mkdir test_easygui
cd test_easygui
curl http://easygui.sourceforge.net/current_version/easygui_v0.93.tar.gz | tar xz
/usr/bin/python2.6 easygui.py
```

EDIT:

Unfortunately, the EasyGui download does not include a setup.py that would allow you to easily install it in the normal Python manner.  To be a good citizen in the Python World, it should.  Fortunately, it is easy to supply one.  In the download directory (`test_easygui` in the example above), create the following text file and name it `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='easygui',
      version='0.93',
      py_modules=['easygui'],
     )
```

Then run the following command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python2.6 setup.py install
```

Now you should be able to run the demo from any directory by:

```
/usr/bin/python2.6 -m easygui
```

and you should be able to just `import easygui` in your own python modules.  By the way, this process should work on any supported python platform (not just OS X) and with any supported python interpreter you have installed: just substitute the proper path for `/usr/bin/python2.6`.  (If you don't have any extra pythons installed on OS X 10.6, typing just `python` should be sufficient.)

Comment: Running into trouble means that the instructions provided at http://easygui.sourceforge.net/current_version/index.html do not seem to apply to Mac OS X 10.6 and the only other information I found ( http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?messageID=91521 ) also does not seem to apply to Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include instructions on how to install into the standard site-packages location.  This should have been included with EasyGui itself!