# Can't figure out how to get EasyGUI for Python set up on my Mac

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, installation, easygui

I'm trying to program a game that would use parts of Pygame and EasyGUI. Problem is, I have no idea on how to set up EasyGUI on my Mac. Just switched from Windows, so I still have some trouble maneuvering inside of it. If anyone could help me, I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 1):

on mac OSX you want to goto finder and select the `go` tab and then select `Go to folder` then copy and paste `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` and right click on the folder and set the access to `read write` for everyone this will allow the install to continue. This does open up that folder for anyone so be careful but this worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what version of OS X are you running, but perhaps this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785987/how-to-install-easygui-on-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard) will help?

Answer (score 0):

To install python packages use ALWAYS pip install it will fix deps and add all you need to the correct path.(that is site-packages in all the platforms)
In your case use pip install easygui, it will install from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easygui

If you need pip you can install it with sudo easy_install pip.